# Transparent background appears for the dynamic columns in grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am developing a grid structure using `div` layout in my application. The `columns` and `rows` are not fixed, they are dynamic, being fetched from the `json` data in AngularJS.

So, it should *scroll* both horizontally as well as vertically, if the `columns` or `rows` or both extend beyond the available `width`.

I have handled it using following CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

The **issue** is that, it doesn't applies the background to the columns and rows which are beyond the grid's width.

**Expectation:** Both the *header* i.e. `column` and *data-list* i.e. `rows`, should be able to inherit their respective `background colors`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/rzsyfvk7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your CSS**

```
.header .display-data {
  background: lightblue;
}

.data-list .display-data {
  background: white;
}
```

[See updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rzsyfvk7/1/)

Comment: I got d idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the CSS you have used to calculate the width of your columns.  You have used `width: calc(100%/3)` for each .display-data column, but you actually have four of these columns.

This means you are setting a total width for the four columns of 133%.  However, the parent .header only covers 100%.  This means that the last 33% is not covered by the .header and, hence, is not blue.

To fix it, just change your .display-data style to `width: calc(100%/4)`.